# Windows 7 Update Error: 80070057

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, updates

I just upgraded my laptop from Windows Vista (32-bit) to Windows 7 (64-bit).
After installing, it performed a critical update and successfully installed 4 of them. It then recognized that there were ~100 more updates to install - with a combination of recommended and important updates.

I hit update, and it wasn't able to download and update for over an hour. I cancelled the update and restarted my computer, but now Windows Update says has never recently checked for them, nor has recently installed any when it had just this morning. In the update history, it shows all of the ones which had been cancelled.

I've run the Microsoft Update Diagnostic, and it comes up with an error: 0x80070057, although when I searched it up, other people's error description did not match mine.

Both Microsoft FixIt and running scannow on the command prompt came up empty - no other problem was detected.

Any other solutions would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Do you have Service Pack 1 installed, if not, download it manually and install it.

Comment: When I downloaded Windows 7, it came with SP1.